# Adjust font for Netbeans

Tags: 16.04, fonts, netbeans

Is it possible to adjust fonts for applications individually? When I set San Fransico font as default all my programs work, but in netbeans the text appears zoomed in.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) *Changing themes and fonts of the desktop and of (specific) applications are two unrelated questions.* So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I would like to ask wheather it is possible to adjust font for different apps because iam facing an issue like when i put san fransico font as default font all my programs work.But in netbeans it is like zoomed in.

Comment: So thats why is posted this question

Comment: yes, I am not sure why the question was closed. Depends on application. `netbeans --fontsize 8` or what ever you like. see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize for additional options / config of netbeans. In the future perhaps be more specific in your questions.

Comment: What's the resolution of your display? Is it a "high-DPI" display?

Comment: Generally, /etc/X11/app-defaults is the location to adjust individual program's defaults, like fonts.  Of course, that presupposes the program actually has such a setting for adjusting X output.